# Best way to Sort-n-Concatenate 5 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sorting

> **!!! WARNING !!!**
>
> Dearest SQL expert, please keep reading before to start to scream.
> this uber-denormalized table structure is
> obtained after apply some
> combinatories-sugar upon a nicely normalized
> set of data : ). I'm avoiding to
> renormalize this resultset because I
> want to keep simple the complete
> process (also this data won't be used
> in another place in the application). (Yes, Codd. I know what you're thinking on).

---

Having five columns containing numeric values

```
 A | B | C | D | E
-------------------
 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 5
 3 | 6 | 1 | 5 | 4
 4 | 5 | 7 | 1 | 3
```

I want to obtain the concatenation of the values after sort them:

```
   ABCDE
-----------
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 3 4 5 6
 1 3 4 5 7
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I don't get it.  Sorting in SQL is done by row.  Are you actually trying to *sort the columns*?  Because that's a sign of a serious design flaw.

Comment: You could write out a 5-column sort in an absurd set of CASE statements... but I agree with @Aaronaught.

Comment: @AaronNaught This table structure is obtained after apply some combinatories-sugar upon a normalized set of data : ). I'm avoiding to renormalize this resultset because I want to keep simple the process (also this data won't be used in another place in the application : )

Comment: Sometimes, for weird cases like this, its easier to perform processing on the client-side than SQL Server. Are you able to move your sorting into your client app?

Comment: Hi Juliet, No. in this case thi should be done in SQL side :)

Comment: What is "combinatories-sugar?"

Comment: @AaronNaught Do you remember the crossjoin stuff from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814649/cross-join-n-times-a-table something like. I'm wondering what is the bet way to normalize all of this Aaron, what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking past the serious questions of why you would need to do this, it can be achieved albeit awkwardly:

```
Select ...
    , Stuff(
            (
            Select ' ' + Z.Col
            From    (
                    Select PKCol, A As Col From Table
                    Union All Select PKCol, B From Table
                    Union All Select PKCol, C From Table
                    Union All Select PKCol, D From Table
                    Union All Select PKCol, E From Table
                    ) As Z
            Where Z.PKCol = Table.PKCol
            Order By Col
            For Xml Path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') As Combined
From Table
```

Obviously, databases were never designed to sort across columns which is why the solution is cumbersome to achieve.

Comment: Hi Thomas! yes, I'm agree. this is non-orthodoxal. but it's just to keep the combinatories process simple (won't try it at home) :) +1