# Cross Join 'n' times a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

It is possible to write a generic function/procedure/select/somethingElse to cross-join a table against himself 'n' times? (yes, 'n' is a given parameter : )

How would you do it?

---

**Example**

Having this table:

```
 Value
-------
   1
   2
   3
```

cross join it 2 times, would return:

```
 Value  | Value
------------------
    1       1
    1       2
    1       3
    2       1
    2       2
    2       3
    3       1
    3       2
    3       3
```

Comment: This is not an intended or appropriate use of SQL. SQL databases are row-oriented with strict schemas, and this would have no clear schema. These operations should be done on rows, not columns.  You could do this with dynamic SQL but it would be *far* better to come up with a proper design instead.

Comment: @AaronNaught I was thinking: what if the crossjoin result were returned in a normalized structure like: (combinationId, value). what do you think?

Comment: It would depend on what you want for the `value`, but you could likely do that very efficiently with a recursive CTE.

Comment: @AaronNaught Hey nice idea! it sounds really good +1. this is exactly the alternative I was looking for. Thank you Aaron!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using dynamic SQL, SQL Server 2005+ (@table_name and @numCrossJoins are stored procedure parameters):

```
DECLARE @upperLimit INT
    SET @upperLimit = 1

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM '+ @table_name +' '

BEGIN 

  WHILE (upperLimit <= @numCrossJoins)
  BEGIN

    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'CROSS JOIN '+ QUOTENAME(@table_name) +' '

    SET @upperLimit = @upperLimit + 1
  END

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

END
```

Comment: This is even SQL Server 2000 compatible.

Comment: Please change @table_name to QUOTENAME(@table_name), sp_executing sql generated from parameter values is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate dynamic sql to output as many cross joins as you need:

```
create table #t (value int)

insert into #t values (1)
insert into #t values (2)
insert into #t values (3)

declare @n int
set @n = 4

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM #t t'
declare @i int
set @i = 0
while (@i <= @n)
begin
    set @sql = @sql + ' cross join #t t' + CAST(@i as varchar)
    set @i = @i + 1
end

print @sql
execute(@sql)

drop table #t
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + replicate('[' + @table_name + '],', @N);

set @SQL = LEFT(LEN(@SQL) - 1);

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to come up with all possible permutations, here is an example:

[All Permutations For A String](http://sqlserver-tips.blogspot.com/2007/07/all-permutations-for-string.html)